# Exception to cause EOL with streamtokenizer?

Tags: java, exception, stringtokenizer

I am writing a small calculator that goes through the input in token form by using streamtokenizer. However, when catching an exception I want it to either ignore all other exceptions, or move to the EOL. I can't just break as the progream isn't meant to crash, just ignore all succeeding exceptions for that input.

So either I try to set up exceptions to ignore every exception following the first, or I try to get streamtokenizer to move to EOL after catching an exception.

Either way I have no idea to get any of the two options functional.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws customException {
    Calculator casio = new Calculator(new Stokenizer());
    while (true) {
        try {
            casio.statement();
        }
        } catch (customException error) {
            System.out.println(syntaxError.getMessage());
        } 
    }
}
```

Stream tokenizer docs is found at http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/StreamTokenizer.html

Comment: Show us the code of `Calculator#statement()`, also that of `Stokenizer`

Comment: Added a link for StreamTokenizer, which is identical to Stokenizer. Statement() (and the rest of the calculator) is kind of irrelevant to the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You could try something like that to go to the end of line:

```
public void statement() throws IOException {
    int tt = StreamTokenizer.TT_EOF;
    try {
        while((tt = tokenizer.nextToken()) != StreamTokenizer.TT_EOF) {
            // ...
        }
    } catch (CustomException syntaxError) {
        System.out.println(syntaxError.getMessage());
        gotoEOL();
    }
}

private void gotoEOL() {
    try {
        while(tokenizer.nextToken() != StreamTokenizer.TT_EOL)
            ;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using A4Ls answer I made a little function and added it before every throw. Probably not the best solution, but it works.

```
private void gotoEOL() {
    while (!tokenizer.isEOL()) {
        tokenizer.nextToken();
       // System.out.println(tokenizer.getToken());
    }
```